# Normalize human names in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, contacts, text-normalization

What is the easiest way to normalize a text field in postgresql table?

I am trying to find duplicates.
For example, I want to consider O'Reilly a duplicate of oreilly. La Salle should be a duplicate of la'salle as well.

In a nutshell, we want to

1. lowercase all text,
2. strip accents
3. strip punctuation marks such as these `[.'-_]` and
4. strip spaces

Can this all be done in one or two simple steps? Ideally using built in postgresql functions.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you what you want, using just standard Postgres functions;

```
regexp_replace (lower(unaccent(string_in)),'[^0-9a-z]','','g')
```

See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4f70c8d28eea6ca76787be4676163871). Or if you do not want digits the just

```
regexp_replace (lower(unaccent(string_in)),'[^a-z]','','g')
```